# “error:23076071:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_parse:mac verify failure” when generating self signed certificate for Identity Server 4

Tags: docker, identityserver4, x509certificate, x509certificate2

We're developing a microservices app on Kubernetes. One of the microservices is IdentityServer instance. Initially, I want to test the solution locally on Docker to make sure it works. For this purpose, I want to copy the certificate to appsettings.json. Eventually this value will be replaced by a Kubernetes secret. In my startup class this is how I'm trying to load my certificate:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
     .AddSigningCredential(GetIdentityServerCertificate())
     .AddConfigurationStore(...


    private X509Certificate2 GetIdentityServerCertificate()
    {
        var clientSecret = Configuration["Certificate"];
        var pfxBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(clientSecret);
        var certificate = new X509Certificate2(pfxBytes, "PasswordHere");
        return certificate;
    }
```

The certificate is generated by me using openssl:

```
openssl req –newkey rsa:2048 –nodes –keyout XXXXX.key –x509 –days 365 –out XXXXX.cer

openssl pkcs12 –export –in XXXX.cer –inkey XXXX.key –out XXXX.pfx
```

Then I get the certificate by using:

```
$pfxFilePath = 'C:\XXXX.pfx'
$pwd = 'PasswordHere'
$flag = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable
$collection = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection
$collection.Import($pfxFilePath, $pwd, $flag)
$pkcs12ContentType = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12
$clearBytes = $collection.Export($pkcs12ContentType)
$fileContentEncoded = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($clearBytes)
```

I grab the `$fileContentEncoded` value and paste it into `appsettings.json`.

When i debug it, the result is: `error:23076071:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_parse:mac verify failure` when i'm trying to create `X509Certificate2` object using the method above.

Comment: The error mac verify failure happens when the password is wrong. Check the password for key with `openssl pkcs12 -in XXXX.pfx`.

Answer (score 5):

The error mac verify failure happens when the password is wrong. Check the password for key with

```
openssl pkcs12 -in XXXX.pfx
```