# IdentityServer4 loading certificates in a Linux Web App in Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, identityserver4, azure-webapps, azure-linux

At the moment I have a web app that works in developer mode, but I am trying to make it work with a self-signed certificate in a Linux Web App in Azure. I have already uploaded the .pfx file to Azure and loaded it into the container by setting the `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` application setting. At first, I tried using the store, however, this does not work in Linux.

Instead, I have already been able to find the file where it is uploaded (to a .p12 file), however, when I try to load the certificate manually I get the error `error:23076071:PKCS12 routines:PKCS12_parse:mac verify failure` which seems to be a problem with the password, but I have verified the password is correct multiple times.

A post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513317/error23076071pkcs12-routinespkcs12-parsemac-verify-failure-when-generating) has the method of generating the self-signed keys using openssl, and shows the same issue.

**Note: Loading the certificate works on both Windows and Ubuntu, just not in the Linux Web App in Azure.**

Comment: What does your code look like that adds the signing keys?

Comment: When I tried to load it from a file:

```var cryptBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes($"/var/ssl/private/{Configuration["WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES"]}.p12");
var cert = new X509Certificate2(cryptBytes, Configuration["CERT_PASSWORD"]);
                
services.AddIdentityServer()
 .AddSigningCredential(cert)
 .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();```

Comment: When I tried to let IdentityServer find and load the cert:

```Configuration["IdentityServer:Key:Type"] = "File";
Configuration["IdentityServer:Key:FilePath"] = $"/var/ssl/private/{Configuration["WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES"]}.p12";
Configuration["IdentityServer:Key:Password"] = Configuration["CERT_PASSWORD"];

services.AddIdentityServer()
 .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();```

Apologies for the bad formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get around this, I used the certificate created through azure with the "Create App Service Managed Certificate" option. The password supplied when loading the certificate is just an empty string ("").

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution of an IdentityServer4 hosted on linux in azure was in this Github Issue: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/4000

The method `AddApiAuthorization()` overwrites the `AddSigningCredential()`!

Furthermore you have to specify the IssuerUrl:

```
  services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.IssuerUri = "https://your.azurewebsites.net/";
            })
```